# ¿En que lugar iniciar git sobre un proyecto en Java?

Tags: java, git

Tengo una pregunta. ¿En que parte de todo nuestro proyecto en Java se inicializa el resitorio en git y que archivos se ignoran?. Como saben los proyectos Java generan una carpeta con muchos archivos e informacion y no se como controlar este proyecto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En la carpeta raíz del proyecto. Si quieres excluir cosas o carpetas puedes utilizar el archivo `.gitignore` para definir que queda fuera de git.

Comment: elegi el que mas te gusta... https://github.com/github/gitignore